# Постраничная навигация пользователей

Tags: php

Пытался сделать на одной странице постраничную навигацию пользователей. Код ниже выдает ошибку. Метод паже простой, меня адрес страницы `http://thesupport.info/admin/users/list.html`. Если что, пасс admin, логин admin@thesupport.info.

```
<?php

// Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных
include "\application\config\database.php";

// Переменная хранит число сообщений выводимых на станице 
$num = 25;

// Извлекаем из URL текущую страницу 
$page = $_GET['page'];

// Определяем общее число сообщений в базе данных 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reznik_memt");
$posts  = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// Находим общее число страниц 
$total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;

// Определяем начало сообщений для текущей страницы 
$page = intval($page);

// Если значение $page меньше единицы или отрицательно 
// переходим на первую страницу 
// А если слишком большое, то переходим на последнюю 
if (empty($page) or $page < 0)
    $page = 1;
if ($page > $total)
    $page = $total;

// Вычисляем начиная к какого номера 
// следует выводить сообщения 
$start = $page * $num - $num;

// Выбираем $num сообщений начиная с номера $start 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reznik_memt LIMIT $start, $num");

// В цикле переносим результаты запроса в массив $postrow 
while ($postrow[] = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo "<table>";

for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    echo "<tr> 
          <td>" . $postrow[$i]['name'] . "</td> 
          <td>" . $postrow[$i]['time'] . "</td></tr> 
        <tr><td colspan=\"2\">" . $postrow[$i]['text'] . "</td></tr>";    
}

echo "</table>";

// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки назад 
if ($page != 1)
    $pervpage = '<a href= ./page?page=1><<</a> 
                                <a href= ./page?page=' . ($page - 1) . '><</a> ';

// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки вперед 
if ($page != $total)
    $nextpage = ' <a href= ./page?page=' . ($page + 1) . '>></a> 
                                    <a href= ./page?page=' . $total . '>>></a>';

// Находим две ближайшие станицы с обоих краев, если они есть 
if ($page - 2 > 0)
    $page2left = ' <a href= ./page?page=' . ($page - 2) . '>' . ($page - 2) . '</a> | ';
if ($page - 1 > 0)
    $page1left = '<a href= ./page?page=' . ($page - 1) . '>' . ($page - 1) . '</a> | ';
if ($page + 2 <= $total)
    $page2right = ' | <a href= ./page?page=' . ($page + 2) . '>' . ($page + 2) . '</a>';
if ($page + 1 <= $total)
    $page1right = ' | <a href= ./page?page=' . ($page + 1) . '>' . ($page + 1) . '</a>';

// Вывод меню 
echo $pervpage . $page2left . $page1left . '<b>' . $page . '</b>' . $page1right . $page2right . $nextpage;

?>
```

Comment: Метка должна отражать используемую технологию.

Comment: вы скажите по конкретней, что нужно сделать